# Programming pattern for lazy loading subcomponents in Ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ember.js

I currently have an ember 1.13 application that exists of a large table, each cell in this table has a tooltip with more information. Currently this is implemented using views and a controller, so when a cell is hovered, it calls back to the controller and dynamically load the correct tooltip.

However now comes 2.0, where controllers and views are deprecated in favor of Components. I can't pass the controller to the component, since this ember prevents me from doing this. And passing the tooltip when the cell is created provides too much overhead since it then becomes eager loading.

What would be the correct way to implement the behaviour I want in a Component pattern? I've been looking at Ember services but I'm not 100% sure this is the correct solution to my problem.

Comment: Controllers are not deprecated, ObjectController and ArrayController are

Comment: @Kitler True, but you can no longer pass a controller as an argument to a component (Passing `{{controller}}` or any path based on it has been removed in Ember 2.0)

Comment: Passing `{{my-component controller=this}}` should give you the context needed though, could you add the tooltip's hover code to the question, might not need it all together.

Comment: That's what I currently do, but what stopped working after upgrading to 2.0

Comment: Can you please add the old code that was in the controller.